# "no swt-win32 in java.library.path" on runtime jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, swt

I am new to Java & Eclipse.  I have a window-based app with dialogs, that works fine inside of the IDE.  However, when I try to export a JAR to make it executable outside the IDE (and thus redistributable), I execute it with the command:

```
java -jar MyLibrary-app.jar
```

I get the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        no swt-win32-4427 in java.library.path
        no swt-win32 in java.library.path
        Can't load library: C:\Users\jay.imerman\.swt\lib\win32\x86\swt-win32-4427.dll
        Can't load library: C:\Users\jay.imerman\.swt\lib\win32\x86\swt-win32.dll
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    at org.jimerman.MyLibrary.MainWindow.open(MainWindow.java:51)
    at org.jimerman.MyLibrary.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:40)
```

I don't know what the difference is between exporting a JAR and a Runnable JAR, I tried both.  On the former, I also tried including the src from the swt project, as well as another Java class library project that I reference.  I am used to visual Studio, and the Setup project, which detects dependencies and collects references for a deployment.  What am I missing?  If I were to use something like Maven, how do I even go about learning what all the terminology and concepts are, to even understand what it means and what I need to build a redistributable file?

Comment: OK, I think I made some headway.  In looking at the beginning of the error, where it says it could not load the DLL's - I downloaded the SWT (4.4) from Eclipse.org, opened the zip.  Apparently just putting the swt.jar file in the same path as my jar, or putting it in the .swt path weren't sufficient.  I opened swt.jar and found the DLL's, and put them in the path it was looking for them (the errors at the beginning), and now my app runs.  Now how do I automate the collection and packaging so I can distribute say a single file to another computer, to run my app?  It's confusing.

Comment: Another thing that worked - when I choose Export on my MyLibrary project, I expand the swt project and from the main folder, select the DLL's to include in my JAR file.  This also executes correctly.  Plus, it is a single JAR zip, so it is a clean build to distribute.

Answer (score -1):

You have an option to export to runnable-jar in eclipse and save ant.xml. It should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project MyLibrary-app">
    <!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
    <target name="create_run_jar">
        <jar destfile="MyLibrary-app" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MainClass"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="bin"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="{Eclipse_HOME}/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_x.x.x.vxxxxa.jar"/>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: So what exactly does this do for me?  What is ANT anyhow?  I guess I'm confused, I am starting from a concrete problem - how to run the Java app I made outside Eclipse.

Comment: this ant.xml made by eclipse when you export a runnable jar, for this file created you should check a box in the wizard. Then check if you have an entry of the jar posted in this answer. You need that jar, if it is absent then you should configure buildpath.